# AWS Step Function Get Details/ARN of running Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am starting a state machine from a python file. The State machine starts a ECS Fargate Task. While the State Machine is running, in my python file can I access the ARN/Details of the running ECS Fargate Task.
Thanks.

Update here is Python Code snippet:

```
def main():
    client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
    
    #For the purpose of this snippet forcing if case to always run
    num = 1
    if num == 1:
        #start state Machine execution
        response = client.start_execution(
            stateMachineArn='arn:aws:states:us-west-2:1234567890:stateMachine:stateMachine',
            input='{"in_put": "{totalPartitionCount:3}"}'
        )

    while True:
        time.sleep(2) 
 
        #Describe State Machine execution while its running
        sf_response = client.describe_execution(executionArn=response['executionArn'])
        status = sf_response['status'] 

# In this loop i am getting state Machine status every 2 seconds. 
# is it also possible to get the ARN/details of my ECS Task from my state machine execution here. 
# I want to use the ECS API to print details about the ECS task in this loop as well.

        if status == 'RUNNING':
            print("%s: %s" % ("> Status...", status))
            continue
        elif status == 'FAILED':
            sys.exit()
            raise Exception("%s: %s" % ("! ERROR ! Execution FAILED: ", sf_response))
        else:
            # SUCCEEDED, ABORTED, ANY OTHER STATE
            print(json.dumps(sf_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
            break

    #At this point state machine execution has finished print output
    print("--------------------------------------------------")
    print(json.dumps(sf_response['output'], indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
    print('--------------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant bit of the Python file?

Comment: @Paolo thanks for getting back to me. I've updated the post with the python excerpt. in the while loop I am trying to access the ECS task ARN/Details so i can use the ECS API to print statistics on the running task as well.